# MVC5 TextboxFor dispay Date without Time

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, html-table

I'm trying to display the date only without the time but nothing seems to work with MVC5. I need to use TextboxFor and not EditorFor. I tried:

```
 <td class="input-pricing">@Html.TextBoxFor(m => new ProjectPricing().UnitTypePriceEffDate,"{0:MM/dd/yy}", new {id = "model-effectiveDate", @class = "date" })</td>
```

and it still shows the time.

```
UnitTypePriceEffDate is of DateTimeOffSet type.
```

I clone the model in jQuery:

```
  $("#model-pricing-row").clone().attr("id", "pricing-row-" + i).appendTo("#pricing-table");
     $("#pricing-row-" + i + " #model-effectiveDate").attr("id", "effectiveDate-" + i); 
    $("#effectiveDate-" + i).attr("name", "Project.ProjectPricings[" + i + "].UnitTypePriceEffDate");
  $("#effectiveDate-" + i).val(selectedUnitTypePriceEffDate[i]);
```

Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to use `EditorTemplate`, e.g. `@model DateTimeOffset @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m, "{0:MM/dd/yy}", new { @class = "date" })`?

Comment: yes but it doesn't work in MVC5. It totally ignores "{0:MM/dd/yy}"...

Comment: Issue seems to be here `new ProjectPricing().UnitTypePriceEffDate`. I tried using your code, shows date without time.

Comment: Seems that `new ProjectPricing().UnitTypePriceEffDate` creates new instance of `ProjectPricing` for every textbox creation instead of simple model binding by lambda expression. Try using a simple viewmodel while avoiding creation of new model instance in view page.

Comment: @User3250: What code exactly did you use? Can you show me exactly what worked for you because for me it doesn't work.Thanks.

Comment: I tried using a DateTimeOffset prop in my Model to show in View. You need to rethink why you want to create a new Class instance in `HtmlHelper` here `new ProjectPricing().UnitTypePriceEffDate`.

Comment: @User3250: Because I'm creating all the textboxes dynamically in jquery. I need the model for validation purposes. Therefore I'm only creating a model  and  then I clone in jquery.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following (I'm assuming that UnitTypePriceEffDate is a DateTime type):

```
 <td class="input-pricing">
     @Html.TextBox("model-effectiveDate",
                    new ProjectPricing().UnitTypePriceEffDate.ToShortDateString(),
                    new { @class = "date" })
 </td>
```